# File Not Found in Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is used to send out daily "huddle" notes for my shift (2nd shift) at work. My goal is to have a button you can click that load's the schedule for the week so people know what their assignments are. There is a folder that contains Excel .csv files with our weekly schedule in it for each shift. There are multiple files with similar names, but the end changes based on what week the schedule is for. For example there might be the following .csv files in that folder:

```
1st_Shift_Week01Jan23
1st_Shift_Week08Jan23
2nd_Shift_Week01Jan23
2nd_Shift_Week08Jan23
```

I would like to have a macro that when clicked, opens up the most recently made file that is applicable for my shift (2nd shift), so that I may copy what is in the most recent schedule file and paste it into our daily notes. Below is the code for the macro. But when I click it, it is saying File Not Found. Our schedule folder has files with the above mentioned names, so I am unsure why it isn't finding a file containing 2nd_Shift as part of the name.

```
Sub Schedule()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileDate As Date
    Dim MostRecentFile As String
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    Dim Shift As String
    Shift = "2nd_Shift"
    
    FolderPath = "S:\Systems\Schedule\"
    
    MostRecentFile = ""
    CurrentDate = Date
    
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & Shift & "*.csv")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileDate = FileDateTime(FolderPath & Shift & FileName)
        If FileDate > CurrentDate Then
            MostRecentFile = FolderPath & FileName
            CurrentDate = FileDate
        End If
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    If MostRecentFile <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=MostRecentFile
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where the loop starts and look at the value for `FileName` - Is it what you expect or is it missing something like a backslash?

Comment: If it looks ok, then step through it using `F8` and check the other variables too as you go.

Comment: If folder name is right spelling in code, please double check the file extension name of csv file. It can be `txt`, `prn` or others. Pls try `Dir(FolderPath & "*" & Shift & "*.*")`

Answer (score 0):

The code tests the file' created or last modified property. But the date of the filename wanted to be tested. This code separate the date part convert it to date and then make the comparison.
Replace the relevant part of the code with this

```
    Do While Filename <> ""
        filedate = Left(Right(Filename, 11), 7)   ' FileDateTime(FolderPath & Shift & FileName)
        filedate = CDate(Left(Left(filedate, 2) & "-" & Mid(filedate, 3), 6) & "-" & Right(filedate, 2))
        If filedate > CurrentDate Then
            MostRecentFile = FolderPath & Filename
            CurrentDate = filedate
        End If
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
```